# Метод покоординатного спуска (метод Гаусса - Зейделя) C#

Tags: c#, алгоритм, математика, численные-методы

Есть алгоритм, который нужно реализовать. Основа для кода готова, смотрите ниже. Проблема заключается в шагах 3, 8. Как понять эти шаги, что используется в C# для нахождения argmin? z равняется 0.5

[image: Предварительное описание алгоритма]

[image: Алгоритм метода покоординатного спуска(метод Гаусса - Зейделя)]

*Где "<----------", должен быть код программы, который еще не реализован*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Linq;

namespace Programm3Console
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int k = 0;
        int n = 3; //count column and line in matrix
        int i = 0;
        double z = 0.1; //коофициент дробления который равен 0.1 или 0.5
        double[] p = new double[n];//предыдущие значение
        double[] x = new double[n];//текущее значение
        double[,] a = new double[n,n];//матрица коофициентов
        double ak = 0; //целое альфа

        int numStep = 1;

        bool isReady = false;

        //alghorithm
        do
        {
            switch (numStep)
            {
                case 1:
                    k = 0;

                    //go to step 2
                    numStep = 2;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    i = 0; //так как первый элемент массива начинается с нуля, то i=0 вместо i=1

                    //go to step 3
                    numStep = 3;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Найти целое альфа     <----------


                    //go to step 4
                    numStep = 4;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    //вычислить x (Текущее значение) <----------

                    //go to step 5
                    numStep = 5;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    if(i==n-1)
                    {
                        //go to step 7
                        numStep = 7;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //go to step 6
                        numStep = 6;
                    }

                    break;
                case 6:
                    i++;
                    //go to step 3
                    numStep = 3;
                    break;
                case 7:
                    if(x[k] != p[k])
                    {
                        k++;
                        //go to step 2
                        numStep = 2;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //go to step 8
                        numStep = 8;
                    }
                    break;
                case 8:
                    //проверить критерий останова <----------
                    break;
                case 9:
                    // Положить h1 = zh1, ..., h = zh и перейти на шаг 2 <----------
                    break;
                case 10:
                    //Положить х* = х <----------

                    //закончить поиск
                    isReady = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }                

        }
        while (!isReady);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

```
double GaussZeydel(double bx,double by,double epsilon,double f_dx(double,double),double f_dy(double,double))//sam metod spuska
{
    /*
    peredelal iz
    https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/896526/
    v pravoslavniy vid
    */
    double x[NMAX];
    double y[NMAX];
    double alpha[NMAX];
    int k;
    x[0]=bx;
    y[0]=by;
    double z = 0.1; 
    //last_x[0]=bx;
   // last_y[0]=by;

    for (k=0; ; k++)
    { 
        alpha[k]=Dihotomia(-1000,1000,epsilon,x[k],y[k]);//yj tochno popady
        alpha[k]= alpha[k]*z;
        x[k]=f_dx(x[k], y[k]);
        y[k]=f_dy(x[k], y[k]);
        std::cout<<"**********["<<k<<"]************"<<std::endl;
        std::cout <<"alpha=("<<alpha[k]<<"),epsilon=("<<epsilon<<") ";
        std::cout<<"x("<<k+1<<"): "<<"("<<x[k+1]<<", "<<y[k+1]<<")"<<std::endl
                   <<"f("<<x[k+1]<<", "<<y[k+1]<<") = "<<f(x[k+1], y[k+1]) <<std::endl;
        if (k>1)
        {
            if (alpha[k]>=epsilon)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```